# Form using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Creating a form using Ruby on Rails

I am a newbie in ROR. I am trying to make a small form.

My index.html.erb file is below:

```
$ cd Code/Ruby/weblog/app/views/welcome/

$ cat index.html.erb

<h1>A Sample form </h1>
<%= form_for :Run do |f| %>
name: <%= f.text_field :name %>
age : <%= f.text_field :age %><br/>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<h5> Built using Ruby on rails </h5>
$
```

The routes.rb file is below.

```
$ cd /root/Code/Ruby/weblog/config
$
$ cat routes.rb
Weblog::Application.routes.draw do
  get "welcome/index"
root :to => "welcome#index"
end

$
```

The form is appearing as expected. But when I click on the "Save Run" box for submitting the form, it's giving the following error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches "/welcome/index"
```

What do I have to do to resolve this error? I need to open another HTML file when the submit button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line into `routes.rb`

`post "welcome/index"`

However, your problem is more than routing issues. Having `welcome/index` to handle your form submission is a bad practice.

Take a look at the [rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes)

Comment: I have added that line in routes.rb . It is not showing the error message also. But its just stay in the same page..Is there any way to display a "Thank you" message or another HTML page  when form is submitted ?

Comment: Make a RESTful runs controller.  I suggest you create a new rails app, run `rails generate scaffold Run name:string age:integer` and study the scaffolded classes.